# Update table columns based on query to the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This has stumped me a bit, and I'm not a SQL guru so please bear with me.

I have a table where each row can have a "parent" (to form a hierarchy). e.g. "Item 1.1" has "Item 1" as it's parent.

The ID column is changing (in this example, from alphanumeric to auto-incrementing numbers).

**How do I populate the new "ParentId" field .. by working out the correct "parent" from the existing column data?**

I have a (very simplified) table as follows:

```
ExampleTable
=============
OldId   OldParentId   Title        NewId   NewParentId
-----------------------------------------------------
A        Null         Item 1       1        Null
B        A            Item 1.1     2        Null
C        A            Item 1.2     3        Null
D        Null         Item 2       4        Null
E        D            Item 2.1     5        Null
```

What I am trying to do is populate the "NewParentId" field, based on a lookup against the existing table.

My (clearly not working) pseudo-code is:

```
Update ExampleTable
Set NewParentId = (Select Top 1 NewId From ExampleTable WHERE OldId = ???.OldParentId)
```

I don't know how to reference the "current row being updated" in the select query.

Is this even the correct approach to achieve this?

Oh - we also need to appropriately identify and handle "nulls" (e.g. "Item 1" and "Item 2" don't have a Parent .. so the Parent ID values should retain their "Null" value)

Comment: You need to explain the logic; What you are trying to achieve is not clear!!

Comment: Ok, I've added a bit more detail to make it more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like:

```
update T
set NewParentId = T1.NewId
from ExampleTable as T
   outer apply (select top 1 T1.NewId 
                from ExampleTable as T1 
                where T1.OldId = T.OldParentId) as T1
```

Comment: You need to add an order by in that top 1 to ensure consistency. In the sample data this isn't an issue but in the real data it might be. I am sure the OP can determine their sort order.

Answer (score 1):

You can join your table to itself using `OldParentId = OldId` and update as follows:

```
UPDATE A
SET A.NewParentId = B.NewId
FROM ExampleTable AS A
INNER JOIN ExampleTable AS B ON A.OldParentId = B.OldId
```

[Full working example](https://gist.github.com/chrispickford/57d1219d98583c2d5a864743c1335390)